# Does matrix multiplication preserve positive semi-definiteness [PSD]?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A,B$ are two PSD matrices, will $AB$ also be PSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AB$ need not be symmetric, try $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Comment: Why do we need symmetry? Is it part of the PSD definition?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Yes.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @user2097

Comment: To whoever read this answer : symmetry has nothing to do with the definition of PSD.